# Or condition Firestore and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to do the following

```
db.collection("...").where("one", "==", true || "two", "==", true || same..).get();
```

But Or condition is not available in firebase, same for .orWhere right? So does anyone have an idea how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: You could try this workaround: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-combined-two-firestore-queries-to-simulate-a-logical-or-query-27d28a43cb2d

Comment: Thank you, I will try it @MichaelD